# Updates to system components BUG

Tags: updates, release-hera, appcenter, bugs

So here's the thing. This component can't be updated from the app center. When I try to click the update button there's no response. It's a bug? or a missing component? This update always appear every time. The os is elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera.

[image]

Here's after I check with `sudo apt upgrade`

[image]

Comment: Try running `sudo apt upgrade` in your terminal and posting the result.

Comment: I agree I'd try ```sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade```

Comment: @m93a check I've already posted the ss like what you ask.